# How to show a popup on multiple marker hover

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I am working on the showing a popup on the marker I can simple add following lines to generate a pop up

```
let marker = L.marker(myloc, { icon: greenIcon }).addTo(map);
marker.bindPopup(map.getCenter() +"<br>" + 
"Min Zoom" + map.getMinZoom() +"<br>" + 
"Max Zoom" + map.getMaxZoom());
```

I am working on showing the nearby markers from my location. I have used leaflet-knn algorithm. From my code I will get 5 marker that are stored in res. Now I have to show the marker information on hover or on click event.

So far I have tried following code. I am getting error. Can anybody help me what I am doing wrong.

```
var longitude = myloc.lng,
latitude = myloc.lat;
var map = L.map('map').setView(myloc, 12),
gjLayer = L.geoJson(testCities);


res = leafletKnn(gjLayer).nearest(
[longitude, latitude], 5, distance);

if (res.length) {
    for (i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        var popup = res[i].layer.feature.properties.name;

        var m = map.addLayer(res[i].layer).bindPopup(popup);

        if ($.inArray(res[i], oldArr) === -1)
            oldArr.push(res[i]);
    }
}
m.on('mouseover', function(e){
    this.openPopup();
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply make a modify to your GeoJSON() function options:

```
var gjLayer = L.geoJson(testCities, {
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        content = "<b>Name:</b> " + feature.properties.name;
        layer.bindPopup(content);
    }
});
```